# Multi-photo upload to album and wall story

Tags: php, facebook, batch-file, photo, history

I'm confident about posting multiple photos to a fan page album through a common batch request with PHP, and I also know how to use che "no_story" command to hide the wall posts showing each image just uploaded. What I need to know is if it's possible to show an unique wall post on the fan page showing the whole upload, like the standard Facebook behavior when you upload more pictures using the web interface, and not one post for each photos.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I have got:

```
$attachment = array
(
'access_token'=>$fanPageAccessToken,
'object_id' => $AlbumId,
'message' => $AlbumDesc,
'link' =>$AlbumLink
);
$result = $facebook->api($fanPageId.'/links/','post',$attachment);
}
```

I get the variables by querying the albums associated with the fanpage:

```
$fanPageAlbums = $facebook->api($fanPageId . '/albums/');
foreach ($this->fanPageAlbums['data'] as $fanPageAlbum) {

if ($albumId == $fanPageAlbum['id']) {
   $albumLink = $fanPageAlbum['link'];
   $albumDesc = $fanPageAlbum['description'];
   break;
  }
 }
```

The key thing is your are posting to the links part of the graph, not the feed.

This works in that it will produce one big picture and three thumbs below it, as you would expect. However, it doesn't appear on the feeds of friends properly.

I've been struggling with this for ages, and the above is the closest I have got to mimicing exactly the facebook behavior. If you get any further please let me know!

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Yes this is a workaround to do something similar, I will use it until i won't find the right solution :)